# Unable To Update Assts in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Here First Time When I am calling updateRegistery only auctionItem is updated to "Selling" and after 1 minute of timeout again updateRegistery is called and this time neither "auctionItem" nor "auction" is updated.
No .catch() function is called which means all promises are resolved successfully.
Please this tell me where i am going wrong?
composer version:-v0.16.4

```
/**Invoked start the auction
 * @param {namespace.StartEnglishAuction} startEnglishAuction
 * @transaction
 */
function startEnglishAuction( startAuction ) {

    var NS = "namespace";
    var auction = startAuction.auction;
    var auctionCreateTime = startAuction.timestamp;

    if( auction.status == "FINISHED" ){
       console.log("Auction is ALready Over");
       return "Auction is ALready Over...!";
    }
    else if( auction.status == "IN_PROGRESS" ){
      console.log("Auction is ALready Running");
      return "Auction is Already Running...!";
    }

    //this updates my auctionItem status to "SELLING" but does not updates auction status in registry
    **auction.status = "IN_PROGRESS";
    auction.auctionItems[0].status = "SELLING";
    updateRegistery(auction,auction.auctionItems[0] );**

    var intervalId = setInterval( checkBidsInterval, 1000 );//checks if auction timeout has occured

    function checkBidsInterval(  ){//called every second after auction is created
      console.log("tick tick");
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if( !auction.auctionItems[0].lastBidTimestamp  ){ //if no bid placed
            //nobody bought item
            var timeoutTime = new Date( auctionCreateTime );
            timeoutTime.setMinutes( timeoutTime.getMinutes() + 1 );
            console.log(" no bid waala case");
            if(  now >= timeoutTime.getTime() ){ 
                //this is called but updates nothing in registry      
                **auction.auctionItems[0].status = "UNSOLD";
                auction.status = "FINISHED";
                updateRegistery(auction,auction.auctionItems[0] );**
                clearInterval( intervalId );
            }

        }

        function sellItem( auction, auctionItem ){
            var factory = getFactory();
            auction.auctionItems[0].status = "SOLD";
          //  factory.newResource( NS, "EnglishAuctionItemSold" );
          console.log("item sold");
          return updateRegistery( auction, auctionItem );
        }

    }//end checkBidInterval

    function updateRegistery( auction, auctionItem ){
      return getAssetRegistry( NS + '.EnglishAuctionItem' )
        .then(function ( englishAuctionItemRegistery ) {
         console.log("rAuctionItem Updated Successfully.!");
         return englishAuctionItemRegistery.update( auctionItem );
      })
        .catch(function( error ){
        console.log("1error ::", error);
        return "fdf";
      })          
        .then(function( earrr ) {
        console.log("earrr", earrr);
        return getAssetRegistry( NS + '.EnglishAuction' );
      })
        .catch(function( error ){
        console.log("2error ::", error);
        return "fdf";
      })          
        .then(function( englishAuctionRegistery ) {
        // add the temp reading to the shipment
        console.log("rEnglishAuction Successfully.!");
        return englishAuctionRegistery.update(auction);
      })
        .catch(function( error ){
        console.log("3error ::", error);
        return "fdf";
      })  

    }  

}//end startEnglishAuction
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see without the model. You also have non-deterministic code (new Date().getTime() ) which can mean issues for your peers agreeing on results (not sure how many peers you have in your setup).

you could try something like this chain to see if both registries are being updated.

```
return getAssetRegistry( NS + '.EnglishAuctionItem' )
  .then(function ( englishAuctionItemRegistery ) {
     console.log("EnglishAuctionItem Updated Successfully.!");
     return englishAuctionItemRegistery.update( auctionItem ) ;
  })
  .then function() {
   return getAssetRegistry( NS + '.EnglishAuction' )
     .then(function ( englishAuctionRegistery ) {
           console.log("EnglishAuction Updated Successfully.!");
           return englishAuctionRegistery.update(auction);
      })
    .catch(function( error ) {
       console.log("Error", error);
  });
```

Similar examples here

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/v0.16.x/packages/perishable-network/lib/logic.js#L85